# how do I access child elements of JSON in the controller in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't understand how to wait for the resource call to finish before assigning the data.properties to $scope in my controller.

here is my confusion:

i have a resource call that returns this:

```
[
{
    "PreAlertInventory": "5.000000",
    "SharesInInventory": "3.000000",
    "TotalSharesSold": "2.000000",
    "TotalMoneySharesSold": "18.000000",
    "TotalSharesBought": "0.000000",
    "TotalShareCost": "0.000000",
    "EstimatedLosses": "0.000000"
}
]
```

here is the applicable code from the controller:

```
$scope.alertSwap = function () {

  var data = Data.query(); // gets the data. works as expected

  //$scope.test = data; //works as expected. can access data and properties in template
  $scope.test = data.TotalMoneySharesSold; //does not work. is empty???
}
```

i can access the array and its properties from the template BUT not from inside the controller.

How do I access the child elements from inside the controller that called the resource?

http://plnkr.co/edit/JnLqq4v7lKlYOHg85Jma?p=preview

## answer: thanks to all who helped:

I needed to assign a callback to the resource call, and assign the elements from within the function:

```
$scope.data = Data.query(myParams, function(data) {
  $scope.test = data[0].TotalSharesBought;
});
```

Comment: please post Fiddle or Plunker to help us to detect the issue. Thanks

Comment: do you get  json as async?

Comment: I assume Your data request is async, you need to put a callback and when it finished assign its value to '$scope.testTwo'

Comment: Your data would appear to be returned as an array, try `$scope.testTwo = data[0].TotalSharesBought`

Comment: @steveukx didn't notice that its list

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/JnLqq4v7lKlYOHg85Jma?p=preview

Comment: @steveukx tried it. no love

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data would appear to be returned as an array, try `$scope.testTwo = data[0].TotalSharesBought`.

I've updated your [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ABAXXGUqnWZJB6EMz56H?p=preview) accordingly.

Comment: this is my actual call. how do i incorporate your answer with this?       var data = Data.query({TradeID:trade.TradeID, AlertID: alertID});

Comment: Call `Data.query(myJson, callbackFn)` where `myJson` is the JSON your are posting and `callbackFn` is the function to call with the response data when it's available. The plunkr currently doesn't have a json parameter in the query, but does call back a response function.

Comment: Thank you for your help i was seriously over complicating this.  answer  $scope.data = Data.query(myParams, function(data) {
 $scope.test = data[0].TotalSharesBought;
      });

Answer (score 1):

As said above it is likely you are fetching those data async. I updated your code to support promise (which makes your code async and may not fit with the rest of the application by the way).

`$timeout` simulates an async call. In your `factory service`:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
$timeout(function() {
    return deferred.resolve(data);
}, 100); // set it to zero to return immediately
return deferred.promise;
```

In your `controller` call you factory factory method `query()` and hook the response with `then`, which is the `promise` part of the snippet:

```
Data.query().then(function(response) {
  $scope.test = response[0].TotalMoneySharesSold;
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/SGGCVS?p=preview

Comment: He loads all his json data to `$scope.data` but can't parse it. Ther is no async problem

Comment: how do i get my factory to return the "response"? this is the factory:

.factory('AlertLoss', function($resource){
    return $resource('http://localhost/shfofx/PHP/Rest/alertLossDetails.php', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', params:{}, isArray:true}
 
    });
});

Comment: i got this code working but it still produces the exact same issue as in the post. the entire array loads but I cannot assign individual elements from inside the controller

Comment: I might not have fully understood your question, but you didn't mention clearly you want to assign a value inside your controller.